# «Unitamente alla presente e-mail si trasmette[ono] copia del file richiesto nonché del relativo codice di accesso»

Tags: grammar

> Unitamente alla presente e-mail si trasmette(ono) copia del file richiesto nonché del relativo codice di accesso.

Cos'è corretto: 'si trasmette' o 'si trasmettono'?

Comment: *Trovate in allegato una copia del file richiesto e il codice di accesso.*

Answer (score 5):

In questa frase *nonché* assume il valore di congiunzione copulativa, al pari di *e*, di conseguenza riterrei più sensato adottare il plurale. Se fosse stato presente un avverbio – *assieme (a)*, per esempio – allora sarebbe stata corretta la forma singolare.

Comment: Giusto, riguardo al fatto che “nonché” è una congiunzione. Ma la frase specifica ha in più la peculiarità di riferirsi a un'unica “copia” con due complementi di specificazione (cioè: non “copia di A nonché copia di B”, ma “copia di A nonché di B”). Diremmo “ci sono la mamma di Gino nonché la mamma di Pino”, ma “c'è la mamma di Gino nonché di Pino”, no? E qui, anche se si tratta di due pezzi di carta diversi, la “copia” in astratto è in un certo senso una sola.

Comment: Credo tu abbia ragione, nello specifico esempio è riferito a *copia*, che non si ripete. Credo di aver riletto la frase così tante volte da aver inventato un altro “copia” fantasma.

Comment: Nel caso di "la madre di A nonché di B" parliamo sí di una sola persona, ma nel caso di "la copia di A nonché di B" non può trattarsi di un solo file (o altro oggetto), a meno che A e B siano uguali. Quindi è sottinteso, secondo me, che la frase è da interpretarsi come "la copia di A nonché (la copia) di B". Io userei il plurale. Sempre tutto IMO.

Comment: @karoshi - Senz'altro, e infatti anche nel mio commento dicevo che presumibilmente “si tratta di due pezzi di carta diversi” (o file, o quel che è), mentre prima mi riferivo solo alla struttura grammaticale della frase. “Il X del Y nonché del Z”, di per sé, è un sintagma singolare.